# Android SQLITE database join tables in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

I have 3 tables in my sqlite android database :

```
ToolTable
---------
_id
serialNumber
TorqueRange._id

TorqueRangeTable
----------------
_id
min
max
TorqueUnit._id

TorqueUnitTable
---------------
id
name
toNmFactor
```

I need to use a CursorAdapter to show a ListView of tools but it seems I have multiple choices to expose datas :

- Use my ContentProvider to return a cursor with all columns I need : _id, serialNumber, minTorque, maxTorque, torqueUnitName
- Only return ToolTable columns and after in each row view make a new request to get TorqueRange by is id :
  _id,serialNumber,TorqueRange._id and after in a TorqueRangeTextView get _id,min,max,TorqueUnit._id

What is the best way to accomplish this? 
Make a join seems easy but after that my ContentProvider returns a lot of columns that I don't need every time.
Make a request inside a custom component view respects more the structure of the database but I don't know if it is a good idea to make a lot of requests.

Thanking you for your lights

Comment: I would go with the first option, although I do not understand completely your problem with that option, you can always set your projection columns everytime you use  a `ContentProvider` so you wont get columns you dont need. The second option is slower by far as you will need to do several of queries (which are not precisely fast).

Answer (score 0):

Ok @zozelfelfo, I choose the first option as you recommanded :

I create my content provider and UriMatcher :

```
private static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
private static final HashMap<String,String> TOOL_PROJECTION_MAP = new HashMap<String,String>();

private static final String TOOL_TABLES = "Tool AS T LEFT JOIN " +
                                          "TorqueRange AS TR ON TR._id = T.TorqueRange_id " +
                                          "TorqueUnit AS TU ON TU._id = TR.TorqueUnit_id";

public static final String KEY_TOOL_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TOOL_SERIAL_NUMBER = "serialNumer";
public static final String KEY_TOOL_MIN_TORQUE = "minTorque";
public static final String KEY_TOOL_MAX_TORQUE = "maxTorque";
public static final String KEY_TOOL_TORQUE_UNIT_NAME = "torqueUnitName";

private static final int TOOLS = 1;
private static final int TOOLS_ID = 2;

static{
  sUriMatcher.add(AUTHORITY,"tools",TOOLS);
  sUriMatcher.add(AUTHORITY,"tools/#",TOOLS_ID);
  TOOL_PROJECTION_MAP.put(KEY_TOOL_ID,"T._id AS T._id");
  TOOL_PROJECTION_MAP.put(KEY_TOOL_SERIAL_NUMBER,"T.serialNumber AS T.serialNumber");
  TOOL_PROJECTION_MAP.put(KEY_TOOL_MIN_TORQUE,"TR.min AS TR.min");
  TOOL_PROJECTION_MAP.put(KEY_TOOL_MAX_TORQUE,"TR.max AS TR.max");
  TOOL_PROJECTION_MAP.put(KEY_TOOL_TORQUE_UNIT_NAME,"TU.name AS TU.name");
}
```

With this line I can query all Tools with torqueRange data and show them in a CursorAdapter but when I need to insert new rows I can't use insert(...) with "content://"+AUTHORITY+"tools/" because I need also to insert a new TorqueRange row.

Is it a good option to replace my content uri "content://"+AUTHORITY+"tools/" by  content://"+AUTHORITY+"toolsWithTorqueRange/" to query in the CursorAdapter, and using "content://"+AUTHORITY+"tools/" for inserting with KEYS :  (KEY_TOOL_ID,KEY_TOOL_SERIAL_NUMBER,KEY_TOOL_TORQUE_RANGE_ID)?

Or are there different options?